# Passes not enabled in provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id, entitlements

Here were my steps.

I created a passtype ID using pass.com.domain.AppName style.

I created an App ID for com.domain.AppName.

I enabled Passes in the App ID.

I created a new provisioning profile with the app id created earlier.

I opened my project in Xcode, set the code signing identity to the profile I had just made.

I Enabled Entitlements, and under passes, told it to use the ones in my provisioning profile.

It said that Passes were not enabled.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure the pass in the provisioning portal after your first step? You need to create a Pass Certificate, it's not enough to just create a pass type ID.
Also don't forget to download the certificate after it's been requested and generated.